# Criterion for weak convergence to $0$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence

In the article I have to read it is claimed that if we suppose that we have a (minimizing) sequence (of some functional) in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n}u_n^2(x)u_n^2(y)|x-y|^{-1} \rightarrow 0$$
then $u \rightharpoonup 0$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. 
The functional in question deals with the Choquard-Pekar problem, we find $u$ minimizing
$$I_{\lambda} = \text{inf}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2 + \frac{1}{2}V(x)u^2 - \frac{1}{4}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n}u_n^2(x)u_n^2(y)|x-y|^{-1}$$
over the set
$$K_{\lambda} = \{ u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n), ||u||_2^2 = \lambda \}$$
We put some conditions on $I_{\lambda}$ to ensure the problem is well-posed, in particular, this guarantees that $u_n$ (minimizing sequence) bounded in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
I have no clue on how to see this. Do there exist similar criteria/techniques for the analogue in $W^{1,p}$?

Comment: I don't think that this is true. This functional does not contain any derivatives of $u$, therefore, minimizing sequences might be unbounded in $H^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Sorry, you are totally right, I added relevant information to ensure this (I did not think of it yesterday evening).